# General contract for flushing and closing streams and channels that wrap another stream or channel

Tags: java, resources, inputstream, outputstream

Closing and flushing IO resources is very important and seldom done correctly (at least by me). The reason for this is that most of the time, it still works without doing it correctly. Files are closed by the garbage collector, which happens from time to time in most applications. Flushing is done automatically when a stream is closed (possibly also by the garbage collector) or when a lot of data is written.

Java 1.7's try-with-resource makes it much easier to close IO resources if their lifetime coincides with the lifetime of a local variable. Not so much if they should e.g. live as long as some other object, but that is another story.

Since I started writing programs that are complex enough that I needed to use resources that wrap other resource, I instead find that it's much harder to decide *what* to close and/or flush than *when* to do it. Examples of wrapping a resource in another resource are:

- Creating an `InputStreamReader` from an `InputStream`.
- Creating an `InputStream` from a `ReadableByteChannel`.
- Creating a `DataOutputStream` from an `OutputStream`.
- Creating a `PrintStream` or `OutputStreamWriter` from an `OutputStream`.

This may also happen multiple layers deep, like wrapping a `ReadableByteChannel` in an `InputStream` in a `GZIPInputStream` in an `InputStreamReader` in a `BufferedReader` (never had to do that but seems plausible). Almost always the wrapping and the wrapped resources should have the same lifetime and it is most convenient if flushing can be done on the outermost resource, where writing is also done, so that only one object needs to be passed around.

In all this time I've never seen a satisfactory explanation of how closing and flushing interacts with resources wrapped in other resources. My assumptions are the following:

- Flushing a resource (i.e. calling `flush()` on it) also flushes wrapped resources recursively until data is pushed onto e.g. the disk or the network.
- Closing a resource (i.e. calling `close()` on it) also closes wrapped resources recursively until some operating system resource is freed.

Now to my question; are these assumptions correct when using JDK implementations of IO resources, specifically of the interfaces `InputStream`, `OutputStream`, `ReadableByteChannel`, `WritableByteChannel`, `Reader` and `Writer`?

If one or both assumptions are not correct at all, what assumptions would be better?

If those assumptions are not always correct, where does the behavior of an implementation differ and what are the reasons?

Comment: Complicating the matters: http://java.dzone.com/articles/common-try-resources-idiom. Cleaning up a resource that is going to be wrapped in another resource if creating the outer resource fails.